# Generate a PDF on Form Submit

Tags: google-apps-script

Hi I am new to the forum and programming Google Scripts.  I am a Technology teacher and I am trying to develop a course tracking software for my students.  I have been watching videos on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpZGvKIHmR8&t) trying to get a Form to automatically generate a PDF and later email that PDF to my students and their parents.   I am at the point where my lack of knowledge is catching up to me. I was able to get the Create PDF function to work on it's own but I cannot get my code to generate a PDF after being triggered by a Form Submit.  When I run the afterFormSubmit function I get the following error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'namedValues' of undefined.  Here is my code and error report - I would appreciate any help I could get.  Thanks in advance!

```
function afterFormSubmit(e) {
  const info = e.namedValues;
  createPDF(info);
}


function createPDF(info){

  const pdfFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById("1jbXL5laCExwwrycDTIearbnXXwwQIms0");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("16r7H5gZAxbwdE_6vWUTUwpOVX8_Cw3oX");
  const templateDoc= DriveApp.getFileById("12qrcjOPVJxuThJVyLARBKcCatkwVNO865lGheUbdDdk");
  
  const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);

  const openDoc =  DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  const body = openDoc.getBody();
  
  body.replaceText("{SEmail}", info['Email Address'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{FName}", info['First Name'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{LName}", info['Last Name'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{PEmail}", info['Parents Preferred Email Address'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{VersionDate}", info['Timestamp'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{GradDate}", info['What year are you scheduled to graduate from Shaker High School?'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{PSequence}", info['What is your preferred Tech Sequence?'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{DDE}", info['Have you taken course 811 - Design and Drawing for Engineering?'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{POE}", info['Have you taken course 812 - Principles of Engineering?'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{WOODS}", info['Have you taken course 850 - Wood Construction?'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{CAP}", info['Have you taken course 817 - Engineering Capstone?'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{ER}", info['Have you taken course 830 - Electronics and Robotics?'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{ADR}", info['Have you taken course 834 - Advanced Robotics?'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{MPE}", info['Have you taken course 835 - Manufacturing Processes for Engineering?'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{ARCH1}", info['Have you taken course 813 - Architectural Drawing 1?'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{ARCH2}", info['Have you taken course 814 - Architectural Drawing 2?'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{HE}", info['Have you taken course 836 - Home Electricity?'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{CAD}", info['Have you taken course 838 - Computer Aided Drafting?'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{FDM}", info['Have you taken course 511 - Financial Decision Making?'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{CEIP}", info['Have you taken course 558 - Career Exploration Internship Program?'][0]);
 
openDoc.saveAndClose();

  const blobPDF=newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info['Last Name'][0]+" "+info['First Name'][0]);
 // tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);


  }
```

[This is the error that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ3jw.png)

Comment: Not exactly solution. Just an advice how you can find a cause of the error. You can use the `Logger.log()` function and see what do you have at some point or your code. For example, it looks like the variable `info` was undefined when you tried to use it in `replaceText()`. You can try to add `Logger.log(e)` `Logger.log(e.namedValues)` `Logger.log(info)` `Logger.log(info['Email Address])` between the lines of your code and look what they will show.

Comment: And how exactly you run the script? If you run it from Script Editor it never will work. It's need to open Form, fill it out, and press Submit button. Only this way the function `afterFormSubmit(e)` can get non-emply object `e`.

Comment: You can actually run triggered scripts from the script editor if you're willing to provide the event object.  You can call them from an intermediate function and create the event object in the intermediate function.  If you're not comfortable with creating objects this may not be the best choice for you.  But it's possible and it provides a method for single stepping through the function using the debugger which is quite useful for diagnosing many problems.

Answer (score 2):

**FINDINGS**

If you're running the `afterFormSubmit(e)` directly from the Apps Script editor, then it is the reason why you're getting the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'namedValues' of undefined` because the `e` parameter needs to be passed with values that will only happen if you perform an actual submit action on the Form.

I've replicated your script and I consistently get the type `TypeError: Cannot read property 'namedValues' of undefined` even when I perform an actual submit action on the Form as the `e.namedValues` contains an empty/null value.

I did some research to know why `e.namedValues` return null values & found a recent issue report comment on [e.namedValues error](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118921815#comment42) that the error encountered was most likely stem from a confusion with the fact that there are two onFormSubmit triggers. One that can be bound to the spreadsheet and one that can be bound to the form.

**RECCOMENDATION**

I've tested the onFormSubmit function using a bound script on a spreadsheet with a created form on it and I was able to make the `createPDF(info)` to work after submitting a form:

1. Create an empty Spreadsheet file
2. Create a form inside that Spreadsheet file
3. Create a bound script inside the Spreadsheet file

***Sample working spreadsheet Bound Script*** that you can use as a reference:

```
function createTrigger() {
    let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('test')
    .forSpreadsheet(ss)
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
}

function test(e){
  const info = e.namedValues;
  Logger.log (info); //Log the info for review
  createPDF(info);
}

function createPDF(info){

  const pdfFolder=DriveApp.getFolderById("DRIVE_FOLDER_ID");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("DRIVE_FOLDER_ID");
  const templateDoc= DriveApp.getFileById("DOCS_FILE_ID");
  
  const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);

  const openDoc =  DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  const body = openDoc.getBody();
  
  body.replaceText("{SEmail}", info['Email'][0]);
  body.replaceText("{FName}", info['Name'][0]);

 
openDoc.saveAndClose();

  const blobPDF=newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info['Name'][0]);
 // tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);

  }
```

**NOTE:** Run the script first from the Editor to authenticate & accept the required permissions (e.g. DriveApp.getFolderById permissions). Then, to test the script, open your Form and try submitting on it.

***SAMPLE FORM***

[image]

***SAMPLE TEMPLATE FILE***

[image]

**RESULT**

***Here's the Execution logs on the Apps Script editor***

[image]

***PDF file was successfully created on the Drive folder:***

[image]

[image]